# Sharing libraries among angular micro app elements

Tags: angular, angular-elements, webpack-externals, ngx-build-plus

I have an micro app element and a shell app which works fine normally. However, I'm trying to build the micro app without the common libraries and refer to them from the global scope. I followed the following tutorial [Building angular elements with sharing libraries](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/your-options-for-building-angular-elements/)

1. ng g ngx-build-plus:externals
2. npm run build:externals (ng serve --extra-webpack-config webpack.externals.js --output-hashing none --single-bundle)
3. The file webpack.externals.js has the following externals defined

   ```
   module.exports = {
   "externals": {
       "rxjs": "rxjs",
       "@angular/core": "ng.core",
       "@angular/common": "ng.common",
       "@angular/common/http": "ng.common.http",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "ng.platformBrowser",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "ng.platformBrowserDynamic",
       "@angular/compiler": "ng.compiler",
       "@angular/elements": "ng.elements",

       // Uncomment and add to scripts in angular.json if needed
       // "@angular/router": "ng.router",
       // "@angular/forms": "ng.forms"
      }
   }
   ```
4. In the angular.json te following scripts are there

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/elements/bundles/elements.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"
            ]
```

But now, the element is not loading in the shell app. It says 
"**Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined at Object.@angular/core"**. 
I'm very new to angular, ave I missed a step here? It looks like the angular.json scripts are not working and element (micro app) is unable to refer to the global array

Comment: Do you solve this problem? How?

Comment: As @ExploreEv has answered, you need to have one app with all the common libraries. Use that scripts.js in the index.js before loading the main.js of the micro apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue as yours, I am trying to embed an angular element into an angular app with ng-build-plus, this is how I resolved it:

1. double check  tag order, place script.js before main.js (so angular get loaded first)
2. add below two scripts above script.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/2.2.10/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.9.1/zone.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but the 2 scripts from ExploreEv somehow didn't solve it. With this help from Manfred Steyer it finally worked:

https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/issues/5

1. run `npm i @webcomponents/custom-elements --save`
2. import this script: `"scripts": [ "node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim.js" ]`
3. make sure polyfills and scripts.js are imported before main.js